# Возможно ли решить проблему фрагментации GPU-памяти на CUDA?

Tags: память, cuda, c++, linux

Добрый день.

Иногда, когда я пытаюсь выделить память, я получаю ошибку "out of memory", хотя функция **cudaMemGetInfo** возвращает количество свободной памяти, которое больше того, что я пытаюсь выделить. Следовательно, проблема во фрагментации. Возможно ее как-то решить? Есть ли способ разместить элементы массива, под который выделяется память, не один за другим, а разбить массив на кусочки и разместить их в разных областях памяти? Но при этом чтобы работать с ним можно было как с целым массивом.

Comment: Насколько я помню, возвращается количество не только глобальной, но и разделяемой, константной и пр. памяти. Может быть, глобальная память уже вся забита, а другие виды, естественно, свободны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведенная далее идея хорошо работает со стандартной моделью виртуальной памяти х86. Для CUDA она, возможно, будет не вполне применима, но все же...

Концептуально это выглядит так: создается свой собственный **диспетчер памяти**, который в начале работы программы захватывает большой кусок непрерывной памяти и *постоянно ее удерживает*. Все прочие компоненты (его *клиенты*) обращаются к нему за требуемой памятью, а он в свою очередь помечает ее как используемую и выдает клиентам. При освобождении же памяти клиентами происходит просто снятие признака занятости, и эта память становится доступна другим компонентам. Это весьма эффективный способ борьбы с фрагментацией памяти.

Разумеется, при реализации надо учесть ряд тонкостей, таких как характер выделения памяти (или *гранулярность*, например, по-страницам), режим освобождения (образование дыр занятой памяти в свободной при непоследовательном ее освобождении) и пр.

Answer (score 2):

Вот именно как **с целым массивом** - сильно сомневаюсь, что такое можно сделать на CUDA'е.

В настольных системах есть такой механизм - **мепирование страниц**, и то, он является скорее побочным продуктом требований масштабируемости систем, поскольку и ОЗУ у них динамическая и механизм подкачки реализуется.

На CUDA'е память скорее регистровая, статическая. Это не требует ее виртуального отображения, поэтому мепирование физических страниц на виртуальные там не требуется. Вот именно мепирование и может такое творить: представлять разнородные физические страницы для пользователя в виде последовательной, плоской памяти.

Но даже если в какой-то момент память на CUDA'е станет расширяемой, по типу настольных систем, все равно мепирование происходит **постранично**. Т.е. при распределении таких массивов будут **кратные ограничения** на число страниц такого массива, в зависимости от размера его элементов, т.е. все равно небольшая, но фрагментация такой памяти будет присутствовать.

Альтернативно задачу можно решить с помощью **списка массивов**: при выделении набора элементов, если не хватает памяти, делим выборку пополам и пытаемся распределить массивы меньшего размера и т.д., пока не будет выделен весь массив.

Comment: А как потом работать с этими массивами? Можно пример кода?

Comment: >А как потом работать с этими массивами? Можно пример кода?

Допустим, элемент списка такой:

 template< typename Type >
 struct GList{
   GList*    Next;
   SIZE_T    Size;
   Type*     Array;
 };
Перебор всех элементов:

 for( GList*L = List ; List ; List = List->Next ){
   for( i = 0; i < L->Size ; ++i ){
     something( L->Array[i] );
   }
 }
Случайный доступ:

 GList*L = List;
 for( ; List && ( ID >= List->Size ) ; ID -= List->Size, List = List->Next );
 if( L ){
   something( L->Array[ ID ] );
 }
ID - индекс элемента, к которому следует обратиться

Comment: А если есть возможность вместо массива использовать списки, то можно сделать еще более простой контейнер (хотя и немного "дороже")

Comment: Расширил ответ, см. отредактированный вариант.